# Windows Subsystem for Linux crashing Windows when "git pull" is run

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, blue-screen-of-death

Has anyone else faced this problem? When I try to run git pull in WSL, the system immediately and consistently crashes leading me to the Blue Screen.

With the stop code:

```
PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA
```

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is likely related to a known bug as described here. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3916

The summary is: Using SSH or Agent forwarding causes the BSOD(Blue Screen of Death). They have reproduced the issue and are working on a fix. That was as of 6 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty the same issue. After some discovering I found out this article. For me, the issue is that McAfee is blocking this action with Exploit prevention mechanism.

Check this link:
https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Endpoint-Security-ENS/blue-screen-mfeepmpk-wsl-git/td-p/616729

Maybe it will help you.
Best regards