# Npm install makes Windows crash

Tags: npm, windows-10, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Generally when I run npm install sometimes my pc crashes and shows the screen like the image below. I’ve tried removing both the package-lock.json and node_modules. I’ve also run the commands npm rebuild -g and npm cache clean -f. 
2 days ago I reinstalled my pc to fabric settings and it still doesn’t help.

I’m using WSL, nodejs v12.10.0 and npm 6.10.3.

Anyone knows what’s up and could help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOg3g.jpg

Comment: Are you using any antivirus software other than Defender? From: [Windows Subsystem for Linux crashing Windows when “git pull” is run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57179531/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I’m using Avast Free Antivirus. Haven’t been a problem since I got it more than a year ago. I’ve also made an exception for the path of wsl in Avast.

Comment: Can you temporarily uninstall Avast (and enable Defender) and see if the crash still happens?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, already on it, thanks!

Comment: This is most definitely an issue I've seen while running npm, and it's super annoying to debug because it's not deterministic and also causes BSOD. I have the same problem with all antivirus (including Windows Defender) disabled.

Comment: @AndrewMao if it’s a problem for you try using yarn for some time and see if it makes a difference. The BSOD was happening much less when I went from Avast to Defender but not to 0. Now I’ve used yarn for a couple of projects and the BSOD has never appeared.

Comment: Roger that on the yarn. This seems like a WSL bug which is in discussion at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4537.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I've been using yarn instead of npm since 3 months back and this problem has never occured again. So if you are experiencing the same problem as me, try it out.